# Round background behind font-awesome button

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a menu consisting of font-awesome icons and text. When a use visits the webapp on mobile. I just want to show the font-awesome icons with a circle as background and no text. So I created the CSS below, but I just can't seem to get it working. Any tips?

```
<a ui-sref="index" class="sub-navigation-button" ui-sref-active="sub-navigation-button-active">
    <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> 
        <span>Exit</span>
</a>

.sub-navigation-button {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sub-navigation-button-active {
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 30px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
    background: rgba(3, 169, 244, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to .sub-navigation-button `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the Font Awesome minified CSS file in your website head section? You should have a line something like the following:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Alternatively, you could copy down the Font Awesome CSS and store it locally with your site. The CSS file will still need to be called in the  section.

Comment: Ok. I think you should be able to do what you're describing using a Font Awesome fa-stack. The icon and circle could both be font awesome display. Here's a code excerpt from something similar I recently did:
<span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
<i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span> --- sorry can't figure how to format this part, hope the example helps!

Answer (score 0):

Bro, check your **import statement**
of font awesome. It matters how you import it on it's behaviour.
Don't use  tag to import font awesome, always use 
tag whose href don't start with "cdnjs". This sometimes hampers the css because js is loaded after the css, that overrides your styling.